# Online Offline status for mysql messaging system -PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have looked everywhere and cannot seem to find out the answer to fix my problem.
I have an online messaging system and i would like to implement Online and Offline status to the users. But no matter what i do with this code... I cannot seem to get it working. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Keep in mind I dont want to alter any of my existing code other than the ones that have to do with `$online` and the `q2` variables.

my code is:

```
<?php
                //show all the users expect me
                $q = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE id!='$user_id'");
                $q2 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT status FROM `users`");
                //display all the results
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q2)){
                $online = $row['status'];
                if($online == "online"){
                    $tcolor = "green";
                }
                elseif($online=="offline"){
                    $tcolor = "red";
                }
                elseif($online ==""){
                    $tcolor= "gray";
                }
                }
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)){
                echo "<a href='/users/pm?id={$row['id']}'><li style='border-left:{$tcolor} 15px solid;'><img src='{$row['pic']}'> {$row['name']}</li></a>";
                }
            ?>
```

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic for setting `$online` is reversed. It should be: `$online = $row['status'];`

EDIT BELOW:

Your original `$q2` was unnecessary as it was just retrieving the status column and nothing was linked to the users. Also, you have all the data you need in `$q`.

```
<?php
    //show all the users expect me
    $q = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE id!='$user_id'");
    //display all the results
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)){
        $online = $row['status'];
        if($online == "online"){
            $tcolor = "green";
        }
        elseif($online=="offline"){
            $tcolor = "red";
        }
        elseif($online ==""){
            $tcolor= "gray";
        }
        echo "<a href='/users/pm?id={$row['id']}'><li style='border-left:{$tcolor} 15px solid;'><img src='{$row['pic']}'> {$row['name']}</li></a>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Looking more closely, you don't need `$q2` statement or loop. I'll edit my answer with updated code.